# Is it possible to access files from the Build Agent container in the TeamCity UI?

Tags: docker, teamcity

I have a build steps that zips up files into a folder that I want to be able to download onto my local machine. The folder as of now gets zipped into the Build Agent that's running in a container.

Is there a way to download this folder from the TeamCity UI, instead of doing docker commands to get it from inside the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure and use [Build artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-artifact.html)

Comment: Ok. So if I have a zipped folder in my C:/ of my BuildAgent how do I configure it to show up in the artifacts.

Comment: I figured it out myself. I knew about Build Artifacts but I was typing in the Artifacts dependencies field instead of the Artifact paths field.